# PowerShell How to check if you are allowed to connect to a specific computer

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am making a script that connects to multiple servers using WMI. I have a `$args1` that has a server that I have access to, `CANCONNECT`, and one that I cannot connect to `CANT`.
In the `foreach` loop I want to write something that does X if I cannot connect and does Y if it can connect. In the `foreach` block I have code that gets info from other servers and It works for everything that I can connect to.

How would I approach this / do this?

This is the code I have so far

```
$args1 = Get-Content .\names.txt
$ArrComputers = 'CANCONNECT', 'CANT'
# $OutArray = @()
$i = 0



foreach ($Computer in $ArrComputers) 
{
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put a `try catch` statement in the `foreach` loop

For the try I did

```
$Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.IPEnabled}
```

and catch I just set the thing to pass as `Failed`

Reference from [here](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/powershell_and_wmi-24/21422/need-help-with-error-handling-get-wmiobject-access-is-denied)